# Error while trying to run command with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm trying to run console command using python library subprocess.
Here's what I get:

```
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> os.system("echo Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
0
>>> subprocess.run(["echo", "Hello, World!"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\trolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\trolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\trolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileNotFoundError` indicates that the first argument in the subprocess.run list of arguments does not exist (in this case, 'echo' does not exist).

`echo` is a shell command (not an executable) and according to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations):

> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a system shell.

To address this, add the `shell=True` argument:

```
subprocess.run(["echo", "Hello, World!"], shell=True)
```

**EDIT**: As noted in the comments, apparently non-Windows systems require all arguments to be a single string:

```
subprocess.run(["echo Hello, World!"], shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.run("echo Hello, World!", shell=True)
```

Comment: Passing a list of strings as the first argument with `shell=True` happens to work on Windows for weird reasons, but really isn't correct.

Comment: @tripleee Certainly doesn't on Linux. I'm curious about the weird reasons.

Comment: @alaniwi I believe on windows it converts the sequence(list in this case) to a string, which seems to be mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows). Has something to do with the underlying `CreateProcess` function that Windows uses.

Comment: The edit is an improvement, but the fact that the incorrect code happens to work on Windows currently is an implementation detail which could change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To run a shell command like `echo`, you want `shell=True`; and then the first argument should simply be a string, not a list of strings.

```
subprocess.run('echo "Hello world!"', shell=True)
```